How do I create a Canvas App using a signed request?
When I attempt to get a signed request from my canvas app, I get an error in the console:
sfdc_canvas_auth=user_approval_required.
When I set Permitted Users to Admin approved users are pre-authorized, I get the following error:
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Does anyone have any experience with Canvas apps that could point me in the right direction?
